# How to transform ConfigureShowFields to generate PDF in sonata admin bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

this is my `ConfigureShowFields` using sonata bundle :

[image: My ConfigureShowFilds description in picture]

I want to transform my data in `ConfigureShowFields` to pdf , is possible ??

Answer (score 2):

Its possible using

https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle

Firstly install and configure the KnpSnappyBundle

Then:

create custom action in your admin:

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    $collection->add('pdf', $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/pdf');
}
```

Create the logic for this action in the admin controller

```
public function pdfAction(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get($this->admin->getIdParameter());

    $object = $this->admin->getObject($id);

    if (!$object) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(sprintf('unable to find the object with id : %s', $id));
    }

    $this->admin->checkAccess('show', $object);

    $this->admin->setSubject($object);

    $response = $this->render(
        '@App/Admin/pdf.html.twig',
        [
            'action' => 'print',
            'object' => $object,
            'elements' => $this->admin->getShow(),
        ],
        null
    );

    $cacheDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.cache_dir');
    $name = tempnam($cacheDir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '_print');
    file_put_contents($name, $response->getContent());
    $hash = base64_encode($name);

    $options['viewport-size'] = '769x900';

    $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('app_print', ['hash' => $hash], Router::ABSOLUTE_URL);

    $pdf = $this->container->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutput($url, $options);

    return new Response(
        $pdf,
        200,
        [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'filename="show.pdf"',
        ]
    );
}
```

Create the pdf view to render the show without admin menu or headers.

App/Admin/pdf.html.twig

```
{% extends '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_show.html.twig' %}

{% block html %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    {% block head %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endblock %}
    <body style="background: none">
    {% block sonata_admin_content %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
    </html>
{% endblock %}
```

Create a print controller in the app.

```
/**
 * @Route(path="/core/print")
 */
class PrinterController
{
    /**
     * @Route(path="/{hash}", name="app_print")
     *
     * @param string $hash
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function indexAction($hash)
    {
        $file = base64_decode($hash);
        if (!file_exists($file)) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        $response = new Response(file_get_contents($file));
        unlink($file);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

NOTE: This controller is used to use knpSnappy with a url instead of string, in order to avoid conflicts with assets, e.g. images etc. If you don't need print images or styles, simply use `$this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->generateFromHtml()` to generate the pdf from the response instead of send to another url and remove the part when is used the cache to create a temporal rendered file.